# Parameter 'Animator' does not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I'm new in unity so I need some help with calling the animations. I'm trying to call an animation on a third collision and I have no errors except this one. I have no idea what to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Lose_Collider : MonoBehaviour
{
int count = 0;
public int score = 0;
public Animator boom;

void Start() {
    boom = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
    if(collision.gameObject.name.Contains("UFO")){
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        count++;
        score -= 500;
        if(count == 1){
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("HP 3"));
        } else if (count == 2){
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("HP 2"));
        } else {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("HP 1"));
            boom.SetTrigger("ExpAnimator");
            //boom.SetTrigger(collision.gameObject.name.Contains("UFO").ToString());
            //Destroy(gameObject);
            //SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
        }
    }
    else if(collision.gameObject.name.Contains("Star")) {
        score += 100;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Animator]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that is not an error, it is a warning. The difference being that with warnings, the game is able to still run. Warnings are helpful tips or reminders that something is not exactly right, but there is built-in error handling to quietly deal with the issue. I would never leave warnings as they exist to let you know that you have most likely missed something in your code, created unintended functionality, or have created a bug.  Your particular warning is stating that your Animation Tree does not contain an Animation Parameter called `ExpAnimato`.

I am going to make an assumption and say you do not have an [`Animation Paramater`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) named `ExpAnimator` but simply want to play the animation or a state in it. If you want to play an Animator, simply call `boom.Play`. If you want to play a specific state inside of the animation on the animator, call `boom.Play("YourStateNameHere")`. There are [other parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) to this function call that can alter how the animator handles the state update.

The other issue I am seeing with your code is you have not assigned the `Boom` reference. As the field is already exposed and serialized in the inspector, assign it by dragging the gameObject from the scene into the field. Right now you are also probably getting a null reference exception when you start the game about how `boom` is un-initialized.

If you want to use a parameter to change the state from say the entry state of `Idle` to your `ExpAnimation`, you need to add a new parameter to your animation state machine. I could try to explain it, but I find it is easier if you [watch someone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw&ab_channel=Unity) do it. There are no code examples in this tutorial, just the setup of the actual Animation State Machine which I think is what you are not familiar with.